# Painting a vehicle black to avoid radar detection: a bad idea?

Tags: thermal-radiation, infrared-radiation, radar

A lot of people on the Radar Detector & Laser Jammer Forum are trying to paint their cars in the deepest black to avoid getting a speed ticket by making their vehicle stealthier for incoming radar waves. Black objects absorbing visible light without emitting or reflecting any would be a violation of the 2nd law of thermodynamics so I have learned that black objects actually emit a lot of radiation in the Infrared to Radiowave frequencies to prevent an increase in temperature.

Now since these are the frequencies that are used by the police to estimate a car's speed, does that mean that painting your car black will actually make it easier for radars to pick up? They don't reflect as much light but they emit more.

Comment: The question is pointless and needs no answer here. If that was the case no black car would ever get a speed ticked. Obviously the operational frequencies of these devices make sure that the signal is adequately bounced of the car.

Answer (score 5):

Night bombers in WW2 were painted black underneath, but it didn't shield them from radar. The reason for the black underside was to make them less visible to searchlights and night fighters, but they could still be picked up on radar, and often were. There are coatings which absorb radar and increase stealth in modern ships and planes, but I don't think they are black in colour. Not the ones I've seen, anyway. Black cars today are not as common as they used to be, but there are still some about. Many have been clocked on police radar, which has no difficulty with them, so to have your nice, scarlet sports car sprayed black would be a lot of trouble and expense for nothing. You might also bear in mind that speed limits are there for a reason and have saved many lives, quite possibly your own.

Comment: That last sentence should be in bold, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

The theory is that because carbon has a comparable resistance to the impedance of free space, it can absorb the energy. That is, it is black at that frequency. But black paint does not noticeably absorb police radar because it isn't nearly thick enough (the thickness needs to be at least a sizable fraction of the wavelength--which is at least a centimeter or so), and because there isn't enough carbon to allow the particles to contact each other, anyway, so it's still simply a dielectric and is thus clear to the radar, letting the energy reflect off the metal of the car. It certainly shouldn't make it easier to be picked up.
By the way, a thick layer of carbon turns the RF energy into heat because the RF induces currents in it, which lose their energy to the finite resistance.

Comment: That carbon foam is a dirty mess: https://www.cumingmicrowave.com/products/carbon-based-foam-absorbers.html

Answer (score 0):

What you emit is not used to measure speed, only to measure your heat.

The wave emitted by the radar device changes parameters when it comes back, reflected from your car, and this is how the speed is computed.
Invisibility from the radar is a complex issue solved at airplanes, not at cars.

What you can do is install a lot of radar devices inside your car that can detect the radar from long distances because the radar use very powerful signals (it needs the signal to come back, remember ?). From long distances a lot of speeds are computed from a lot of cars so you are in a safe area, you can detect it before you came to the radar close range where it became proof in the court (a close-up photo is added to the speed detection, with your plate number).
Pay attention that in many countries radar detection devices are illegal so people are starting to mount them in hidden places with hidden ways to be started, But this may be illegal, too. Check the law.

Why people are destroying super sports cars with that stupid paint, nobody knows, probably they are running away from Bill Gates electronic chips from the vaccines :-)

Radar is reported by systems like Waze or radio stations that the trucks used. These are not illegal, yet.

Pay attention that using speed in places without visibility, intersections or using old cars can lead to crashes and loss of lives.
If you feel tired reduce the speed under the legal limits and even stop for fresh air, coffee, or 1 hour of sleep in the car.

Comment: Simplest way to avoid the vaccines is to not take them. No need for black paint.

Comment: This answer is irrelevant of what its is actually asked.

Answer (score 0):

I might, but ONLY if I were repainting/refinishing the car anyways, and then it would be just another option, alongside candy apple red, charcoal metalflake, flip-flop, and pearl.
In that light, "stealth" paints can be justified. 1) it's another "look," remembering that taste is subjective and good taste is questionable.
b) it can be argued that the stealth qualities of flat, non-reflective paints may have the greatest effect on simple human sight. those ultra matte-blacks are simply less noticeable than bright, flashy colors.
3)if you're painting anyways, and you're already considering it as a finish, then whatever percentage of effectiveness you grant to full-black radar/lidar absorbing "stealth" paints are secondary benefits of the paint behind personal taste and old-school inconspicuousness.
Finally,if you do paint in flats and mattes don't forget to consider your head and tail lights, your highly-reflective license plates, and of course,  windshields and back glass.
As I understand the tech, although radar/lidar does reflect off engine blocks and radiators, it has to pass through body panels and grills twice; once heading at the car and again on the way back to the radar gun. it would follow that passing through a "stealth" finished body panels - twice - would logically degrade the echo to some degree.
so, anyways, yes. I DO like the look of mattes and flats. I've never owned or driven cars painted in any shade of Ticket-Me-Red or Impound-Yellow. So if I were going to paint anyways, then yes, I might indeed use a "stealth" paint.

Comment: Welcome to [Physics.se]. The focus of this forum is physics, but this answer  doesn't discuss that aspect of the question very much at all. As such, it may be deleted as being off-topic.